# Backbone View event not firing after upgrading Backbone from 0.9 to 1.2

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-events

I have upgraded my web application from Backbone 0.9.10 to Backbone 1.2.1, and everything is great with one exception.  See the code below:

```
define( ['underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/myResults.html'], function (_, Backbone, Template) {

  var myView = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: '#myResults',

    initialize: function (options) {
        this.targetLoc = options.targetLoc;         
    },

    events: function() {            
        var _events = {};
        _events ['show ' + this.targetLoc + ' a'] = 'tabClicked';           
        return _events;
    },

    tabClicked: function (e) {
        ....stuff....
    }

    template:  _.template(Template),

    render: function() {
        var outputHTML = this.template({model: this.model.toJSON()});
        this.$el.append(outputHTML);
        return this;
    }   

  });

});

return myView;
```

Before I upgraded Backbone, my `tabClicked` event fired without issue.  Now it doesn't fire, and when I `console.log(this.targetLoc);` in the `events` function it says that `this.targetLoc` is *undefined*.

I even tried adding:

`this.events['show ' + this.targetLoc + ' a'] = 'tabClicked';`

to the `initialize` function to no avail.

This application is using:

- jQuery 1.9.1
- jQuery UI 1.10.3
- Underscore 1.8.3
- Bootstrap JS 2.3.1
- Require 2.1.5
- Backbone 1.2.1 (formerly 0.9.10)

Obviously something changed from 0.9 to 1.2 of Backbone, any ideas on how I can fix my problem?

Comment: Probably the 1.2.0 change described in the [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog). *Views now always delegate their events in setElement. You can no longer modify the events hash or your view's el property in initialize.*. I'm guessing this also affects using a function in the `events` property and that `this.targetLoc` is undefined when your event-function is called because it's called before `initialize`. You can check if that's the case with a debugger or a `console.log`.

Comment: @ivarni that should be an answer

Comment: @coding_idiot It doesn't help the OP fix the problem, it just explains why the problem is there. Most likely the solution is to find another way to inject that `targetLoc` thing to the view or change the architecture so it's not needed but there's not enough context in the question to come up with a good workaround.

Comment: @ivarni The myView view is a nested view that gets called N times based on the number of results I have.  The targetLoc is a variable that is used to determine what data to show for each myView view.  Unfortunately, it needs to be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [changelog](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog), in 1.2.0 there was a change to how views delegate their events

> Views now always delegate their events in setElement. You can no longer modify the events hash or your view's el property in initialize.

So you can no longer rely on attributes you've set in `initialize` to dynamically create your event hash. However, there's also a `constructor` that you can use.

A quick [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/CE1AjVZiRsJq85N152Z1?p=preview) on plunker shows that this works with 1.2.2.

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
  constructor: function(options) {
    this.eventTarget = options.eventTarget;
    Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  events: function() {
    var _events = {};
    _events['click ' + this.eventTarget] = 'clicked';
    return _events;
  },
  clicked: function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  },
  render: function() {
    this.$el.html('<a class="foo">click</a>');
  }
});
```

Basically you should be able to work around this change by moving the logic that `events` rely on into the `constructor` instead of doing it in `initialize`. The only caveat is that you must remember to call the original constructor of `Backbone.View`.

So try to replace your `initialize` with

```
constructor: function (options) {
    this.targetLoc = options.targetLoc;
    Backbone.View.apply(this, arguments);         
},
```