# Which is the best way to add events handler dynamically in Backbone.View?

Tags: events, backbone.js, backbone-views

In my previous project , i use Backbone.js of version 1.1.2 , and the `Backbone.View` is defined as

```
var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    options || (options = {});
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    this.delegateEvents();
};
```

As i update my Backbone to the latest version(1.2.3) , now the `Backbone.View` is defined as

```
 var View = Backbone.View = function(options) {
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('view');
    _.extend(this, _.pick(options, viewOptions));
    this._ensureElement();
    this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

The difference is the `delegateEvents` now is moved to the `setElement` method , thus i can't dynamically change the 
`events` property of `Backbone.View`. But in some situation , i think dynamically change events is needed , for example,
i have a `FileRowView` which extends `Backbone.View` to represent file information , its template html string is :

```
<li>
    <h3 class="title">File name</h3>
    <p>File description </p>
</li
```

The problem the title dom can be clicked and do something , but in other situation it can't be clicked , so in the `events` hash , i can
control this behavior in the initialize method just like :

```
var FileRowView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName:'li',
    tmpl:
        '<h3 class="title">File name</h3>'+
        '<p>File description </p>',

    events:function(){
        var events = {};
        if(this.options.canClickTitle){
            events['clcik .title'] = this._titleClickHandler
        }
        return events ;
    },

    //
    // options = {
    //      canClickTitle:false
    //      ...
    //      ...
    //  }
    //
    initialize:function(options){
        options = _.extend({}, {
            canClickTitle:true
        } , options);
        this.options = options ;
        this.render();
    },

    _titleClickHandler:function(){
        console.log('some action');
    },

    render:function(){
        var html = _.template(this.tmpl)();
        this.$el.append(html);
    }
});
```

But in the new version `Backbone.View` , as the `delegateEvents` has been added to the `setElement` method , how can i dynamically add event handler in the `events` property ?

In the version 1.2.0 the change document say:

> Views now always delegate their events in setElement. You can no longer modify the events hash or your view's el property in initialize.

I don't know why ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32211924/957731

Answer (score 1):

I'd turn the problem around a bit and use the tools you already have rather than trying to force them to work the way you think they should.

For example, you could make your template look like this:

```
<h3 class="title <%= is_clickable ? 'clickable' : '' %>">File name</h3>
<p>File description</p>
```

Then include an `is_clickable` flag in the data you feed the template and your `events` would be simple and static:

```
events: {
    'click .clickable': '_titleClickHandler'
}
```

Or if you need more specificity:

```
events: {
    'click .title.clickable': '_titleClickHandler'
}
```

Now you don't have to do anything weird or version dependent and you don't have to fight the framework.

Comment: Thanks. Of course by this way , we can resolve the problem ,but for the problem , i can also use the jQuery.on() method in the initialize method to dynamiclly add event handler , in my opinion ,  framework's existence is aim to deal with the common code design pattern problem . We should keep our code more clean and readable.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery's `on` like that? My answer is AFAIK the idiomatic way to do this sort of thing in Backbone. I'd even say that using an extra class is the right way to do it with plain jQuery too, it even lets alter the cursor through CSS. What you're trying to do is a bit odd.

Comment: Yes, I know your way may be the best way to do the work  with consideration of the latest Backbone framework. But the problem is your way is also add an event delegate even if I totally don't need it in some situation.For example , TableViewA --> FileRowView ; TableViewB --> FileRowView , in TableViewA the title is clickable , in TableViewB the title is not clickable , if I want to reuse FileRowView and use it in TableViewB , I have to add an unneeded delegate event and pass other clickable flag.

Comment: So what? Does it matter in any noticeable way? If it matters, use separate views for clickable and non-clickable rows rather than trying to mess around with flags.